# Proper Code or Design Pattern to select combination of items from an enum

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, enums

I want to select multiple items from a enum based on the some of parameters. So, for example suppose I have an enum named Animal

```
public enum Animal
{
   [DisplayName("Dog")]
   Dog,
   [DisplayName("Cat")]
   Cat,
   [DisplayName("Mouse")]
   Mouse,
   [DisplayName("Ant")]
   Ant,
   [DisplayName("Monkey")]
   Monkey
}
```

And I want to get only specific items from this enum based on the parameter, so if my parameter is "FourLegged" I should get Dog, Cat, Mouse, for other parameter I should get different set. And there could be multiple combination of enum and parameters, I can pass one or more pararmeter to get related items from the enum.

What should be the best/proper way to implement this? Is there any code or design pattern to implement this? It can be other approach than using enum.

Comment: you should design it with classes because `enums` in c# are awful. f# discriminated unions could solve your problems but not c# `enums`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = typeof(Animal);

        foreach (MemberInfo item in t.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            if (Attribute.IsDefined(item, typeof(FourLeggendAttribute)))
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
}

public enum Animal
{
    [FourLeggend]
    Dog,
    [FourLeggend]
    [AnotherOne]
    Cat,
    [FourLeggend]
    Mouse,
    [AnotherOne]
    Ant,
    Monkey
}

public class AnotherOneAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class FourLeggendAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Abstract

The key idea is to use specific method for each thing you want to describe. One implementation of this is to create helper class with static methods like

```
class AnimalHelper { 
  public static bool isFourLegged(Animal a) {//your code here}  
}
```

and calls like `if (AnimalHelper.isFourLegged(dog)`
but **it's not a good idea**: in OOP **each dog should know about his legs** and anybody else should not count its leg but asks dog 'How many legs do you have?'. I suppose, using helpers is evil. Possibly it's a lesser evil but it's not good anyway.

In Java world (where I came from) each enum is a rightfull class and you could add any methods you want and has any number of properties inside each `Animal`.

### Traits

In C# you could add a [methods to your enum as trait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.enum(v=vs.110).aspx#methods) so you could incorporate to you `Animal` additional knowledge

```
// great idea to put it in the one file with Animal if possible
public static class Extensions { 
  public static bool isFourLegged(this Animal animal) {
     // an example for using hardcoded values. 
     // You should alter this method when you add another Animal
     return animal == Animal.Dog && animal == Animal.Mouse
     // oops, someone added Cat after me
  }
  public static Collection<Animal> getAllFourLegged {
     // use dynamic way like in answer from Andrea is good
     // but *probably* cause perfomance issues
  }
```

and use it like `if (dog.isFourLegged())`.

### Class hierarchy

If your `Animal` has many properties and you expect some behaviour from it (like `aCat.eat(aMouse)` or `aDog.go(aPlace)`) then you could want to create class hierarchy `class Cat extends Animal` and then create enum `AllCreatures`. This give you more flexibility for the cost of more complexity

---

Please note I'm a stranger in C# world and could miss something important